# Is there a way to transparently use move or copy constructor in a template?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a generic thread safe queue in a way that can work both with move-only objects or copy-only objects. Here is what I tried (I removed all the irrelevant code (locks) for the sake of simplicity):

```
struct MoveOnly
{
  MoveOnly() = default;
  MoveOnly(const MoveOnly& a) = delete;
  MoveOnly& operator=(const MoveOnly& a) = delete;
  MoveOnly(MoveOnly&& a) = default;
  MoveOnly& operator=(MoveOnly&& a) = default;

  std::vector<int> v;

};

struct CopyOnly
{
  CopyOnly() = default;
  CopyOnly(const CopyOnly &a) = default;
  CopyOnly &operator=(const CopyOnly &a) = default;
  CopyOnly(CopyOnly &&a) = delete;
  CopyOnly &operator=(CopyOnly &&a) = delete;

  std::vector<int> v;
};

template <typename T>
class Queue
{
  std::queue<T> q;

public:
  T pop()
  {
    T t = q.front();
    return t;
  }

  void push(T&& t)
  {
    q.push(std::forward<T>(t));
  }
};

int main()
{
  Queue<MoveOnly> qm;
  qm.push(MoveOnly());
  MoveOnly mo = qm.pop();

  Queue<CopyOnly> qc;
  CopyOnly c;
  qc.push(c);
  CopyOnly&& co = qc.pop();
}
```

There are several compile errors due to `pop`: `T t = q.front()` cannot work with move semantics as the function returns a lvalue reference.  `T t = std::move(q.front())` would not work with an explicitly deleted move constructor as operator overloading will resolve to the deleted constructor. The same kind of problem used to appear in the `push` function but it is resolved with perfect forwarding.

Another problem is apparently that `return t` binds to the move constructor for `CopyOnly`, and I have difficulties to understand why it does so.

**Is there a way to make `pop` work with both `MoveOnly`and `CopyOnly` objects?**

---

*Side question:* does it make sense to define an object like `CopyOnly`with explicitly deleted move constructors? In which case would it be useful to do that? Because it works if the constructors are implicitly deleted.

Comment: Aside: what's the purpose of a copy only type? move is conceptually a copy.

Comment: Yes I am also asking that question actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use *constexpr if* and check if `T` is `std::move_constructible_v`.

I'd also create an `emplace` proxy:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Queue {
    std::queue<T> q;

public:
    decltype(auto) pop() {
        if constexpr(std::is_move_constructible_v<T>) {
            T t = std::move(q.front());
            q.pop();
            return t;
        } else {
            T t = q.front();
            q.pop();
            return t;
        }
    }

    template<class... Args>
    decltype(auto) emplace(Args&&... args) {
        return q.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

---

Here's a C++11 version (I didn't notice the C++11 tag before). Deleting the move constructor and move assignment operator in `CopyOnly` really made a mess out of it. You should probably never do that in real code.

To get `CopyOnly co = qc.pop();` to work, `pop()` needs to return a `const T` or else the move constructor will be part of the overload resolution, which it still will be even though it's deleted, but compilation will fail just because it's deleted.

If `CopyOnly&& co = qc.pop();` is ok for you, you can replace the `const U` with `U` in the `enable_if`.

```
template<typename T>
class Queue {
    std::queue<T> q{};

public:
    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<std::is_move_constructible<U>::value, U>::type
    pop() {
        U t = std::move(q.front());
        q.pop();
        return t;
    }

    template<typename U = T>
    typename std::enable_if<!std::is_move_constructible<U>::value, const U>::type
    pop() {
        U t = q.front();
        q.pop();
        return t;
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        q.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

---

Here's another C++11 version built on rafix07's idea with an extra `popper` type that does the `pop` after return to take care of a possible bug in gcc 7.3.

```
template<typename T>
class Queue {
    std::queue<T> q{};

    struct popper {
        std::queue<T>& q_ref;
        ~popper() {
            q_ref.pop();
        }
    };
public:
    using Type = typename
        std::conditional<std::is_move_constructible<T>::value, T, T&>::type;

    T pop() {
        popper pop_after_return{q};
        return std::forward<Type>(q.front());
    }

    template<class... Args>
    void emplace(Args&&... args) {
        q.emplace(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Comment: Cheers for that @Jarod42 :-)

Comment: `pop_front` was indeed  missing from OP code. So `is_move_constructible` is really better than `is_copy_constructible`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Come to think of it ... it should be `pop()` and not `pop_front()`, right? The `queue` calls the container's `pop_front()`

Comment: Strangely, google shows me `deque` before `queue`, when I search for "std::queue::pop_front" to check :-/ and I bindly check first link... sorry.

Comment: It looks like a great solution, but does not work with c++11, is there a way in c++11?

Comment: @Jarod42 That's fine! I appreciate the intention.

Comment: @MartinCastin It'll become a little more verbose, but sure. I'll try to add that.

Comment: Well as stated in the other answer, I think there is a bug in GCC 7 (that I use) that leads to "error: use of deleted function ‘CopyOnly::CopyOnly(CopyOnly&&)’ return t;", which probably means there is no proper way with the compiler I am using. But I guess you're right and explicitly deleting the move constructor should never be done in real code, so I'll probably return to my first `std::move` solution

Comment: @MartinCastin Oh, ok. I added a workaround for that.

Answer (score 2):

You can add to your queue:

```
using Type = std::conditional_t< std::is_move_assignable_v<T> &&
   std::is_move_constructible_v<T>, T, T&>;
```

then `pop` looks like:

```
T pop()
{
    std::decay_t<Type> t = std::forward<Type>(q.front());
    q.pop();
    return t;
}
```

if `T` is moveable, by `std::forward<Type>(q.front())` move constructor is called (`front` is casted to be *rvalue reference* to trigger move construction). For `T` as copyable, copy construction will be performed.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Phimd8)

Comment: I am using C++11 so I translated your code as 
```using Type = typename std::conditional< std::is_move_assignable<T>::value &&
                                 std::is_move_constructible<T>::value, T, T&>::type; ```
and 
```typename std::decay<Type>::type t = std::forward<Type>(q.front());```

Comment: Indeed, under c++11, `::type` and `::value` are required.

Comment: However, I see your demo compiles with clang, but with gcc 7.3, I get "error: use of deleted function ‘CopyOnly::CopyOnly(CopyOnly&&)’  return t;" (that I already encountered before but I don't really get where it comes from)

Comment: I also noticed in the demo you had to declare an additional template U for the push method, why is that?

Comment: Because you want to use forwarding reference there, so you have to turn it into template function. Yep, you are right, it starts to work since G++8.1, :D,  [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/R8qtw_). But in g++7.1 should also work, because when move cannot be performed, copy is done, what your class supports. Strange thing.

Comment: For `T&& t` it is not allowed to pass *lvalue* as argument, because *lvalue* cannot be bound to *rvalue reference*. It concerns forwarding reference.

Comment: I think I like this better than my suggestion (at least for C++11) so you got my vote. Is `std::decay` needed though? `static_assert(std::is_same<T, typename std::decay<Type>::type>::value);`  passes - at least for the used types.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi, you mean decay for `decay<T> t` ? without `decay`, we will have `T&` for `front`, so after `pop`, this reference  will be dangling. By decay, we force copy or move constructor to be called.

Comment: I meant `std::decay_t<Type>`. It always becomes `T`, doesn't it?

Comment: Right, it is always `T`.